# How to restore the index of a QComboBox delegate in a QTableView?

Tags: python, qt, model, pyqt, qcombobox

There is a `QTableView()`, one of it's column is filled with `QComboBox`es.
The question is how to select item in combobox that is in `QTableView()` according to data taken from dictionary

I see that I should apply `self.combo.setCurrentIndex(self.combo.findText( status_str))` but can't understand how to get that variable `status_str` in `comboBox` or place in code where to apply it.
Also I cannot understand how make `comboBox` appear only after double clicking. If cell was not double clicked it must looks like any other cell.

The sample of code:

```
data = {"first":{"status":"closed"},"second":{"status":"expired"},"third":{ "status":"cancelled"}}
class ComboDelegate(QItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        QItemDelegate.__init__(self, parent)
    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        self.combo = QComboBox(self.parent())
        li = []
        li.append("closed")
        li.append("expired")
        li.append("cancelled")
        li.append("waiting")
        self.combo.addItems(li)
        #self.combo.setCurrentIndex(self.combo.findText( status_str ))
        if not self.parent().indexWidget(index):
            self.parent().setIndexWidget(           index,          self.combo          )

class TableView(QTableView):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QTableView.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.setItemDelegateForColumn(1, ComboDelegate(self))

class MainFrame(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        table = TableView(self)
        self.model = QStandardItemModel()
        table.setModel(self.model)
        MainWindow = QVBoxLayout()
        MainWindow.addWidget(table)
        self.setLayout(MainWindow)
        self.fillModel()

    def fillModel(self):
        for i in data:
            print i
            name_str = i
            status_str = data[i]["status"]
            name = QStandardItem(name_str)
            status = QStandardItem(status_str)
            items = [name, status]
            self.model.appendRow(items)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = MainFrame()
    main.show()
    main.move(app.desktop().screen().rect().center() -     main.rect().center())
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Overriding `QItemDelegate.paint` is not the recommended method for creating a delegate. `QItemDelegate` has methods such as `createEditor` and `setEditorData` which you should override instead. These methods are called appropriately by Qt.

In `createEditor` you should create your `comboBox`, and return it. For example:

```
def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
    editor = QComboBox(parent)
    li = []
    li.append("closed")
    li.append("expired")
    li.append("cancelled")
    li.append("waiting")
    editor.addItems(li)
    return editor
```

In `setEditorData` you query your model for the current index of the combobox. This will be called For example:

```
def setEditorData(self, editor, index):
    value = index.model().data(index, Qt.EditRole)
    editor.setCurrentIndex(editor.findText(value))
```

Note that in this example, I've relied on the default implementation of `QItemDelegate.setModelData()` to save the current text of the `combobox` into the `EditRole`. If you want to do something more complex (for example saving the `combobox` index instead of the text), you can save/restore data to a different role (for example `Qt.UserRole`) in which case you would modify where you get the role in the `setEditorData` method as well as overriding `setModelData` like so:

```
def setEditorData(self, editor, index):
    value = index.model().data(index, Qt.UserRole)
    editor.setCurrentIndex(int(value))

def setModelData(self, editor, model, index):
    model.setData(index, editor.currentIndex(), Qt.UserRole)
```

Here is a minimal working example of the above code! Note that I've turned off support for `QVariant` using `sip` so that the model returns native Python types.

```
import sys
import sip
sip.setapi('QVariant', 2)
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *


data = {"first":{"status":"closed"},"second":{"status":"expired"},"third":{ "status":"cancelled"}}

class ComboDelegate(QItemDelegate):

    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        editor = QComboBox(parent)
        li = []
        li.append("closed")
        li.append("expired")
        li.append("cancelled")
        li.append("waiting")
        editor.addItems(li)
        return editor

    def setEditorData(self, editor, index):
        value = index.model().data(index, Qt.EditRole)
        editor.setCurrentIndex(editor.findText(value))


class Example(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()

        self.tableview = QTableView()
        self.tableview.setItemDelegateForColumn(1, ComboDelegate())

        self.setCentralWidget(self.tableview)

        self.model = QStandardItemModel()
        self.tableview.setModel(self.model)
        self.fillModel()

        self.show()

    def fillModel(self):
        for i in data:
            name_str = i
            status_str = data[i]["status"]
            name = QStandardItem(name_str)
            status = QStandardItem(status_str)
            items = [name, status]
            self.model.appendRow(items)


if __name__ == '__main__':    
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

### EDIT

I've just noticed your other question about automatically showing the the `comboBox`after you double click. I have a hack for doing that to which I've used before. It relies on passing the view into the delegate and adding the following lines to the `createEditor` method:

```
        editor.activated.connect(lambda index, editor=editor: self._view.commitData(editor))
        editor.activated.connect(lambda index, editor=editor: self._view.closeEditor(editor,QAbstractItemDelegate.NoHint))
        QTimer.singleShot(10,editor.showPopup)
```

Full working example:

```
import sys
import sip
sip.setapi('QVariant', 2)
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *


data = {"first":{"status":"closed"},"second":{"status":"expired"},"third":{ "status":"cancelled"}}

class ComboDelegate(QItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self, view):
        QItemDelegate.__init__(self)
        self._view = view


    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        editor = QComboBox(parent)
        li = []
        li.append("closed")
        li.append("expired")
        li.append("cancelled")
        li.append("waiting")
        editor.addItems(li)


        editor.activated.connect(lambda index, editor=editor: self._view.commitData(editor))
        editor.activated.connect(lambda index, editor=editor: self._view.closeEditor(editor,QAbstractItemDelegate.NoHint))
        QTimer.singleShot(10,editor.showPopup)

        return editor

    def setEditorData(self, editor, index):
        value = index.model().data(index, Qt.EditRole)
        editor.setCurrentIndex(editor.findText(value))


class Example(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()

        self.tableview = QTableView()
        self.tableview.setItemDelegateForColumn(1, ComboDelegate(self.tableview))

        self.setCentralWidget(self.tableview)

        self.model = QStandardItemModel()
        self.tableview.setModel(self.model)
        self.fillModel()

        self.show()

    def fillModel(self):
        for i in data:
            name_str = i
            status_str = data[i]["status"]
            name = QStandardItem(name_str)
            status = QStandardItem(status_str)
            items = [name, status]
            self.model.appendRow(items)


if __name__ == '__main__':    
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That is the exact solution I tried to find.

Answer (score 0):

In order to not always see a combo box in the cell, you need to subclass [`QAbstracItemModel`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html) or similar, and set it as model of your `QTableView`, so that you can override its `data()` function, which describes what should be displayed in each column.

Then, to have the combo box appear on click, and make it correctly display the selected index, I suggest you to have a look at [`QStyledItemDelegate`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyleditemdelegate.html).

It is best if you read up on it yourself and figure out the details, but here is a rough outline on how you can use it:

1. Subclass `QStyledItemDelegate` and in that subclass have your `QComboBox` as member.
2. Override its `createEditor()` function to return the combo box. Thus, when you set this delegate as item delegate of your column, the combo box is shown for editing.
3. Subclass `QAbstractListModel` and set it as model for your combo box. It will hold the entries of your combo box and will ensure that always the correct index is shown without you needing to search for the index.

Again, read up on how each of these steps is correctly done, for instance how to correctly subclass an abstract model. You can find all the information in the "details" section of each class's documentation.

Comment: There is no need to subclass `QAbstractItemModel` given they are already using `QStandardItemModel`. You can use `item.setData(data, role)` instead.

Comment: @three_pineapples so I tried `status = QStandardItem()  status.setData(status_str, Qt.EditRole)` it shows combobox and every cell in status column has the same chosen status despite of what the value of `status_str` is. Could you please explain with example what should I do. I do read documentation but lack of experience doesn't allow me to bind together bare information without examples

Comment: @SergiiArtele I'll try and find time to provide a full example soon. Bug me if I forget!